# Rails way to detect mobile or web device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to send an email to user to confirm their account. My app have only mobile version so I want to detect case when user will open email and click confirmation button using web browser. In such case I need to display instruction to go to the mobile app. But in case when it's opened by mobile the confirmation button should redirect to the app and confirmed whole account.

Is there any rails way to distinguish between these two cases? I'm using devise for all email mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can access the [request](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#method-i-request) method.

You can create a helper method like this to get the `user_agent` :

```rb
def mobile_device?
  request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
end
```